# Picker SelectedItem Binding Issue in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms, binding, picker

I have a Picker bounded to a ObservableCollection object. The items are populated from a web service (json data).

The picker displays the data correctly, but the SelectedItem doesn't work.

Here is my xaml code:

```
  <Picker
        ItemsSource="{Binding RatesTax}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Code}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SourceRate, Mode=TwoWay}">

    </Picker>
```

RatesTax is an object of RatesView class

```
 public class RatesView 
{
    public string Code
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public double TaxRate
    {
        get; set;
    }      
}
```

and this is the propertie

```
 public ObservableCollection<RatesView> RatesTax { get; set; }
```

this is the sourceRate atribute

```
private RatesView sourceRate;
```

and the SourceRate properties

```
   public RatesView SourceRate
    {
        set
        {
            if (sourceRate != value)
            {
                sourceRate = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SourceRate"));
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return sourceRate;
        }
    }
```

I put a Break Point in SourceRate to see if it enters when I pick some data of the picker but it does not enter in the SourceRate procedure. I thinks SelectedItem="{Binding SourceRate} is not working as expected.

thak you for your time!

Comment: the types of SelectedItem and ItemsSource do not match

Comment: thank you for your answer! so SourceRate new to be a RatesTax object?

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectedItem` property must be of the same type as your items in the collection. So in your case, the `SourceRate` property and its backing field `sourceRate` must be of type `RatesView`.

Also make sure that your binding is two-way by setting `Mode=TwoWay` in your binding:

```
<Picker
    ItemsSource="{Binding RatesTax}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Code}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SourceRate, Mode=TwoWay}">
</Picker>
```

Comment: `public RatesView SourceRate
        {
            set
            {
                if (sourceRate != value)
                {
                    sourceRate = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SourceRate"));
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return sourceRate;
            }
        }`                                                                 `private RatesView sourceRate;`

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to also make your backing field `sourceRate` type `RatesView` as well.

Comment: I make the changes but still not working, if I put a break point in  `public RatesView SourceRate
    {` it would have to stop when you select one item from the picker no? because its not stooping.

Comment: Try changing your binding to look like this: `SelectedItem="{Binding SourceRate, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: Are you saying if you set a breakpoint within the `SourceRate` setter, it does not get hit when you change the selected item?

Comment: When I select an item in the picker never fire the SourceRate property

Comment: My error was binding to string type and not the ItemsSource type, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bug on Xamarin side. If you make your SourceRate a string, you will get your selected Code when picked. It does not route the bound object for some reason, but only Display value. It does not seem a desired/intended behavior.